# Using A Different Regex Engine in Python

Tags: javascript, python, regex, performance, python-re

Python uses the "Python" regex engine re; this implementation is very slow.  I want to try and use the ECMAScript implementation of regex in my python code... is there a way to do this?  Here's my regex that finds IPv4 and IPv6 addresses:

```
(?:(?:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){6}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})|(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}::(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,5}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})|(?:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){2}:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,4}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})|(?:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){3}:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,3}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})|(?:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){4}:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0,2}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})|(?:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){5}:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:)?[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})|(?:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){6}:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){0}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})|(?:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){1,6}[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}::)|(?:(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})::)|(?:::(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){1,6})[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|(?:::(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})))(?!\:)|(?<!\.)(?:(?<![0-9])(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?![0-9]))(?!\.)
```

It may be able to be optimized further (suggestions are welcome) but, when I put it into [regex101.com](https://www.regex101.com) with some beefy test data, it becomes quickly apparent that EMCAScript is much faster than the Python version...
[image: ECMAScript Flavor Regex finds 21523 matches in 505.2ms]

[image: Python Flavor Regex times out]

Implementing the Python flavor in Python is as simple as "import re"

What are the steps to implementing the ECMAScript (JavaScript)  flavor that is fast enough (505.2ms) to run my code

The Python version takes around 3 seconds to run!

I am trying to implement the ECMAScript version into python

Comment: Could you include some test data?

Comment: Additionally, I suspect Python is showing up as slower because you are running it though a browser and all the details of how they are running/timing the regex are hidden. A precompiled regex run locally will give you a better idea of the real timing.

Comment: Nobody ever told that python is fastest language. But there are plenty of third-party regular expressions modules which are faster then built-in `re`.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I guess I'm asking what those third-party modules are?

Comment: @Viglione I haven't run the EMCAScript version locally but the Compiled Python version does take 3 seconds on my relatively beefy local machine

Comment: @Viglione The test data I am using is sensitive, I can update the post with some different test data but I can't really make any more simplifying assumptions since the data will come in all sorts of shapes and sizes

Comment: @TrevorHurst, I've meant [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) which might be faster. Generally, if your task is to scrape huge data blob using regular expression, you probably want to do it using something faster than python. Check [this](https://github.com/mariomka/regex-benchmark) comparison.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I have tried that and It is actually slower with my Regex for some reason... I think it has to do with backtracking and lookahead/behinds

Comment: I see no reason to not write 10-lines script on Nim/Rust which will process your text around 100 times faster if you're really seeking for productivity.

Comment: @OlvinRoght How would I call that from my existing python script?

Comment: I have no clue what are you trying to do actually. If task is rather simple, I'd switch to Nim completely. Also it depends on real-world difference you got. If it will save you 3 minutes - just leave it like it is. If it can save hours - start thinking about optimizations.

Comment: I suspect you could optimize this by using `[0-9a-fA-F:]+|\d+(\.\d+){3}` and then filtering the results based on which successfully parse to IP addresses using [`ipaddress.ip_address(address)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.ip_address).

Comment: @Ouroborus That regex is slower because it has too many false-positives; also the ipaddress.ip_address() function is not very well optimized; I'm running thousands of IPs through.  I do like your regex though!!